# How to test the output of an NgForm function in angular

Tags: angular, observable, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to test the result from submitting my form in angular but I am not sure what to expect. I have created my mock data and created a spy with with jasmine but I write the expect.
I know it returns an Observable but how do I test that?

My template

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="post_donation_form(f)">
  <!-- form fields -->
</form>
```

---

```
const testForm = <NgForm>{
    value: {
        address: {
            billing_address: '10500 N De Anza Blvd',
            billing_city: ' Cupertino',
            billing_state: 'CA',
            billing_zipcode: '95014'
        },
        billing_email_address: 'test@gmail.com',
        billing_first_name: 'Tim',
        billing_last_name: 'Cook',
        billing_phone_number: 2044567894,
        given_to: 'NumbersUSA Action',
        gross_gift_amount: 1000,
        recurring_subscription: false
    }
};
```

My component

```
save_donation(form_data: NgForm) {
    return this.donationService.post_donation_form(form_data.value).subscribe(
      data => return data );
}
```

This is my test case but I am not sure how to write the expect to compare it with the mock.

```
    it('should post the form values to the server', () => {
            const spy = spyOn(service, 'post_donation_form')
.and.returnValue(Observable.from([testForm]));
            donation_service_component.save_donation(testForm);
            expect(donation_service_component.save_donation).toContain(testForm);
        });
```